# NameError: name 'mag' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

My code :

```
if message.content == "pingrole":
    role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == "ping", mag.server.roles)
    await client.add_roles(member, roles)
```

The error is :

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/PC/Desktop/mylittlebotMK2.py", line 26, in on_message
    role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == "ping", mag.server.roles)
NameError: name 'mag' is not defined
```

I got a client.run command too but want to secure my token.

Answer (score 0):

probably add ( where you are creating it, not shown in your code ) :

global mag

to make the object reachable in the local context of your function.

to get rid of error "mag" must be defined as a globally reachable variable for the script mylittlebotMK2.py

Comment: doesnt work, im a newbie at python too so I need more detail about things if you could provide

Comment: you would need to show us where "mag =" is set ( if it is ) in your code maybe use pastebin if too long

Comment: aand there isnt any... could you give me example of the command ?

Comment: there should be, if you are modifying some random script you found ( and already has bugs ) without basic python knowledge. i fear you won't get much help without whole code and an idea of what you want to achieve.

Comment: alright let me edit the page to have the full code... im trying to achieve a discord bot that gives a role when a command is called out